# How to call (headless) chrome from Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, google-chrome-headless

I have this system command that works great at generating a pdf (from the terminal):

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=example.pdf http://google.com
```

But I can't run it from a Rails server, here's the output:

```
> chrome = "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome"
> system("#{chrome} --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=#{tmp_filename} #{report_url}")


[0821/135833.989767:WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(181)] dns_config has unhandled options!
    [0821/135833.990086:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1016)] Lost UI shared context.
    Started GET "/assessment/responses/1/download" for ::1 at 2018-08-21 13:58:34 +1000
    [0821/135834.126445:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(292)] Failed to load /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/68.0.3440.106/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib: dlopen(/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/68.0.3440.106/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib, 1): image not found
    Started GET "/dashboard?id=1" for ::1 at 2018-08-21 13:58:34 +1000
    [0821/135834.377142:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(292)] Failed to load /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/68.0.3440.106/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib: dlopen(/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/68.0.3440.106/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/68.0.3440.106/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib: file system sandbox blocked stat()
    [0821/135834.430067:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(201)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
```

I'm guessing that Rails has a special environment and Chrome isn't loaded into that environment? How do I run this command from the Rails server?